# Можно ли переменную использовать вместо ссылки?

Tags: php

```
echo "<a href="<?php echo $e; ?>">".$_POST['text']."</a>";
```

Ошибка вот здесь:

```
<?php echo $e; ?>
```

С одинарными теряется пост запрос и выгружается сразу `$e`:

```
echo "<a href='<?php echo $e; ?>'>".$_POST['text']."</a>";
```

Comment: у вас двойные скобки внутри двойных скобой.

Comment: ответ пишите в поле для ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что echo в echo. Вот ваш вариант:

```
echo '<a href="' . $e . '">' . $_POST['text'] . '</a>';
```

Comment: Что именно у вас в $e и в $_POST['text']?

Comment: В $e разместите только сам адрес, без html-кода и кавычек.

Comment: И зачем вы содержимое сайта размещаете в атрибуте href ссылки? :-)

Comment: В $e у вас всё содержимое сайта, а в href дожен указываться только «голый» адрес.

Comment: Думаю, что вам нужно создать новый вопрос, где привести полное описание что нужно и свой код. Так — это только гадать. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='".$e."'>".$_POST['text']."</a>";
```

У вас была нарушена структура, вложенность: после echo шли открывающие тэги, так не должно быть. Я использовал конкатенацию и вставил одинарные кавычки, чтобы в html-коде ссылка отобразилась нормально.